# TideSDK Windows publish timeout error

Tags: windows, titanium, tidesdk

I use TiDev Community and TideSDK 1.2.0 RC4, but when start compiling Windows version app get timeout error. It proceed 2 weeks.
Previously this was no error. What change?

My system is Windows7 x32, build 7600.

Comment: Did you try to launch your app for debugging reasons, or did you try to package the app for distribution?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see a traceback or to have additional details on what you were doing. TiDev as an app that is reaching the end of its useful life cycle. I believe the issue for you is that you may have attempted to produce packages over the network. While TiDev has options for network packaging, Appcelerator (who used to run the service) indicated that they would not maintain it longer term.

We are currently working on the TideBuilder app that will take the place of TiDev in the near future. We have options for how we may replace the network packaging service but currently are focused on getting the 1.3.0-beta to a release. Until then, we currently recommend using tibuild, a command line utility, to create a bundle package.

If you need more information, or you feel the issue may be a different one, please provide some additional details so we can help you futher.